# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

I was working on my project and everthing worked fine. I tried to open the server in another browser and this error appeared. I stopped the project and start it agian and it stop working on my main browser aswell. I dont have any idea what this cause it.

```sh
Internal Server Error: /account/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\Python\Python391\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "A:\repos\topanime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 244, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
[18/Mar/2021 18:52:01] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86400
```

If there is any other information that you need tell me.

Comment: What version of django? Did you update anything recently?

Comment: 3.1.7. I used this version from the beginning

Comment: The problem is that I don't even know what caused this. I just stopped the server and run it again and this is what I got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a view in `context_processors` that required login `@login_required`. So I couldnt load any page because i wasnt logged in

Comment: So what do you replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@login_required` in **context_processors**:

The way I solved it was by replacing it with an **if statment** inside the **context_processor**.

```py
def myCP(self, *args, **kwargs):
   kontext = {}
   if self.user.is_authenticated:
      # The user is logged in
      kontext['loggedIn'] = True
   else:
      # The user is logged out
      kontext['loggedIn'] = False
   return kontext
```